# Task to Deploy Artifact to a container Storage Outside of my account

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am currently creating a CI for the FrontEnd of one of our client.

We need to copy the file coming from our repo the container account of the compagny that manage the operational part (we are only providing the code).

So , the company that will manage the infrastructure has Given us the storage account name (testdeploy) , the container name (artifact-deply) and the key (securekey).

I have managed to connect to the storage via Azure Storage Explorer , but now I need to deploy the artifact on this container via the CI.

The problem is , I don't know how , and I can't find documentation on how to proceed , every doc talk about deploying to a container in the same subscription.

But I do not have acces to this container , I only have it's name and key.

Here is the Yaml to what I have already setup , I do not know if i can help:

```
steps:
- task: AzureFileCopy@2
  displayName: 'AzureBlob File Copy'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_listes-Azure/buildtest'
    azureSubscription: 'Paiement à l''utilisation(my_subscription)'
    Destination: AzureBlob
    storage: testdeploy
    ContainerName: 'artifact-deploy/front'
    AdditionalArgumentsForBlobCopy: 'securekey'
    outputStorageUri: 'https://testdeply.blob.core.windows.net/'
    outputStorageContainerSasToken: 'securekey'
```

Of course when i do this I have this error message :

```
2019-10-25T10:45:51.1809999Z ##[error]Storage account: fprplistesdeploy not found. The selected service connection 'Service Principal' supports storage accounts of Azure Resource Manager type only.
```

Since It's not in my subscription scope , it can't acces it.

What I am doing wrong ?

I am using the AzurFileCopy task , is it good?

How can I setup the AzurFileCopy task to a container account that is not on my subscription scope , knowing that the only thing i have is a account name , and a key?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you basically have to do is to create and use a Shared Access Signature (SAS) to deploy resources into this blob container. Since you have the storage account key you can create a SAS token with Azure Storage Explorer.

Then use Azure Cloud Shell or Azure CLI on local machine for testing purposes. Try to copy a file into the blob container using a SAS token for authorization. If you have problems with authorization using a SAS token you can also test access using Azure Storage Explorer. Such basic tasks are widely known and well documented.

Finally find a way to run the file copy command used while testing in an Azure Pipeline Task. If [Azure File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops) does not fit to your use case, use a more generic task like an [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops). From reading over the docs it might be that it does not support your use case although the task name indicates that. I see your point. Find out how to access the artifact provided by the build pipeline and copy the file resources into the storage account. If that basically works find out how to improve it. Voila.

Comment: Thx ! After some reshearch I found out that your solution is the only way to do it. I find it rather stupid that you cannot copy to a blob via SAS token with Azure File Copy Task... I will thinker with Azur CLI and upload it here once I figured it out , Thx for you clear answer

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to do it.

Turns out , you can't do it via the AzureFile Copy , this task can't upload to as Container outside your subscription.

You must use an Azur CLI task , here is the script I used:

```
#!/bin/bash

az storage blob upload --container-name artifact --file $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/artifact_deply/buildtest/front.zip --name front --account-key securekey
```

I changed all the variable but the idea is here ( I declared the account name in the variable panel of azur devops).
I used the account key , because I had error with the SAS URL , but I think you can easily use the Azur devops variable to pass the SAS Token URL.

And I created a task before this one to zip all the folder , so it's easier to manage.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I recommend to ask another separate question to address your issue with a SAS URL.

Comment: Hi Popopame, I see that it was done a long time ago, but hopefully, you be able to help. I have exactly the same task, and according to your suggestion trying to use Azure CLI, but it also asks for Azure Subscription. Not sure how to avoid it, because I'm trying to upload to the different instance. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Figured it out, I used regular PowerShell taskm instead of azure CLI and was able to connect to the 3rd party BLOB.